# How to create popups in css /Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am trying to make popups containing list of lines:

1. Support
2. Contact
3. Demo

In the 1st line, it should display Support. In the 2nd line, it should display Contact and in the 3rd line, it should display Demo.

I was able to create popups containing one line by following the w3schools link http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup but I am not sure how to create popups having multiple lines.

The pictorial representation of what I am trying to get is shown here:
[image: Popups with multiple lines]

The code which I have used from the w3schools link is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <style> /* Popup container - can be anything you want */ .popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; }

/* The actual popup */ .popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px; }

/* Popup arrow */ .popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent; }

/* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup */ .popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s; }

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */ @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;} }

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;} } </style> <body style="text-align:center">

<h2>Popup</h2>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!   <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Support</span> </div>

<script> // When the user clicks on div, open the popup function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');
    popup.classList.toggle('show'); } </script>

</body> </html>
```

In place of A Simple Popup, I have written Support. At this moment, I am able to get only one line as shown here: [image: One line Popup]

Comment: What have you tried?  Pretty simply the only thing you are doing is toggling between a hidden and shown element.  Therefore you just need to add to the element you are toggling.  I suggest using an unordered list and list items instead of a `span`.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick try do these steps to design what you want

1- open [you mentioned link](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_popup)

2- change the html code to :

```
 <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Click me to toggle the popup!
<div class="popuptext" id="div">
     <div><span id="myPopup">Support</span><br/></div>
     <div><span id="myPopup1">Contact</span><br/></div>
     <div><span id="myPopup2">Demo</span><br/></div>
</div>
</div>
```

3- change `myFunction()` code block to :

```
var popup = document.getElementById('div');
popup.classList.toggle('show');
```

4- Add this `css` class to `style` element in `head`

```
 .popup .popuptext div{
   text-align: center;
   background:#ad4747;
   border-radius: 6px;  
   width: 160px; 
   margin-top:2px; 
}
```

5- At the end run and see the result

but as you know there are several ways to design popup menu by front-end tools ,

but my solution is a quick design hope give you some help.

[Additional helpful link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/StyledDropdown/)